Nuclear fusion within a star and escape of light
I understand that light photons travel through the layers of stars from the core, and that they start mainly as highly energetic gamma radiation, I also know that it takes hundreds of thousands of years even millions of years to "escape" the core and bring visual light to the surface, So my question is, was the Sun or any star completely dark for the first thousands or million years because light was still trapped?

The starlight you see is emitted by the photosphere not because of nuclear fusion, but simply because it is hot. And it become hot because of pressure much before fusion in the core starts.

No, because the idea that light is produced in fusion reactions and then percolates slowly to the surface is incorrect.
The interior of a star is a very, very good approximation to a blackbody.  Every bit of it, including those parts harbouring nuclear fusion and those parts which are not, is emitting (and absorbing) a Planckian radiation spectrum according to its temperature. Indeed "pre main sequence stars" that are not undergoing any significant fusion are more luminous than their older main sequence counterparts.
The reason that radiation diffuses outwards (it isn't the same photons gradually working their way outwards) is that there is a temperature gradient, meaning there is a slight asymmetry in that there is more outwardly directed than inwardly directed photons at any point. The individual photons travel just a mm or so in the stellar interior until near the surface (the photosphere), the path length increases and outwardly directed photons can escape.
